# Variable independece in marginal integration estimator

Tags: generalized-additive-model, nonparametric-regression

This is an exercise of the textbook *Nonparametric and Semiparametric Models* by Wolfgang Hardle

> Exercise 8.1. Assume that the regressor variable $X_1$ is independent from $X_2, \cdots, X_d$. How does this change the marginal integration estimator now? Intepret the change.

We know that the estimation of marginal effects for additive models is
$$
\hat{g}_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\widetilde{m}(\cdot\ ,\ X_{i\underline{\alpha}})-\overline{Y}
$$
where $\widetilde{m}$ is a multidimensional pre-smoother and $X_{\underline{\alpha}}$ indicate the absence of the $\alpha$-th component.
But I don't get how to use the condition of independence. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.